# HostListener para escutar uma variavel

Tags: angular, angular-6

Estou tentando implementar um evento `HostListener` para ouvir a alteração de uma variável.

Tenho um exemplo que está funcionando, mas está escutando toda a página e eu quero ouvir apenas um pequeno pedaço de código.

Esta é a parte que eu quero ouvir:

```
<select class = "intenção-retângulo" (change) = "listQuantity = $ event.target.value">
    <opção [ngValue] = "10" valor = "10"> 10 </ option>
    <opção [ngValue] = "25" value = "25"> 25 </ option>
    <opção [ngValue] = "50" value = "50"> 50 </ option>
    <opção [ngValue] = "100" valor = "100"> 100 </ option>
</select>
```

Este é o meu `HostListener` atual que está funcionando:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) onNumEachPageChange($event) {
   this.setArrayPages()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc pode fazer assim:

```
<select class="intenção-retângulo" (change)="onClick($event.target.value)">
   <option></option>
</select>
```

Ele irá chamar o method ao clicar no select

```
onClick(data: any) {
        console.log('data', data)
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou